# How to do insert statement to input multiple ids in a column? SQL statement

Tags: sql, structure

There are two tables, first one is `country_sports` with columns `country_id`, `country_name`, `sports_id` and `date`. Second one is `sports` with columns `sports_id`, `sports_name`, `sports_date`.

When I post a form in web app by giving `sports_name` and choose the list of sports, then I want to create a insert statement that selects the `sports_name` and gets the list of sport's id and put it into the first table 'country_sports'.

Here, `sports_id` should have multiple ids.

For example,

```
insert into country_sports (country_id, country_name, sports_id, date) 
values ('', '', '', curdate());
```

For example, the data structure should be

```
('1', 'germany', '1, 2, 3, 4', 12-02-2017);
```

Comment: I think you have to prepare 4 separate inserts in your example.  You didn't specify which database.

Comment: @etsa, It is MYSQL database.

Comment: You are describing a ManyToMany relationship, which would mean you would have to add a 3rd table which has fk_country_sports_id and fk_sports_id, the table is there to show the relationships between country sports and sports

Comment: @RubyvanSoelen, Yes, I could create a new table that links two tables with their foreign keys however it would be easier for me to store the data in country_sports and linking only one table sports.

Comment: @etsa, I came up with insert into country_sports (country_id, country_name, sports_id, date) select (''. '', '', curdate() union all); Is this do able?

Comment: The "multiple ids column" is just a string, according to the database it does *not* contain a list of ids. In database terms it is *much* easier to use an extra ManyToMany relation table, for instance to find all countries where they have a specific sport.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

IF sports_id IS NOT NULL THEN

```
BEGIN

    SET @sportsID_list = CONCAT('''',REPLACE(REPLACE(sportsID,' ',''),',',QUOTE(',')),'''');

    SET @ sportsID_stub = REPLACE(@sportsID_list,',','');

    SET @ sportsID_array_count = LENGTH(@sportsID_list) - LENGTH(@sportsID_stub) + 1;

    SET @x = 0;

    WHILE @x < @ sportsID_array_count DO

            SET @x = @x + 1;

            SET @sqlv = CONCAT('SELECT ELT(',@x,',',@ sportsID_list,') INTO @sportidobj');

            PREPARE v FROM @sqlv; EXECUTE v; DEALLOCATE PREPARE v;

            SET @sqliv = CONCAT('INSERT INTO  table_name (`Id`,`sportId`)VALUES (',@countryId,',',@ sportidobj',')');

        PREPARE spv FROM @sqliv; EXECUTE spv; DEALLOCATE PREPARE spv;

    END WHILE;      

END;
```

END IF;

This is dynamic sql query used to insert multiple records binding with one record.
Replace the fields and table name as per your need.